# How to take input for timer with 11 buttons

Tags: java, input, timer, android-view, countdowntimer

I am new to android development . I am trying to make a timer app . My UI has 11 buttons from 0-9 , a 00 button and a backspace button . The initial format of my textview will be like "00h 00m 00s" . When a user type input like "123" the textview should change from right to left like "00h 01m 23s" . I cant figure out how to do this.
It should take input like google clock app
GOOGLE CLOCK APP

[image: GOOGLE CLOCK APP]

PLS WRITE CLEAR CODE IN JAVA .

I tried using three textview for h , m and s .  I used SpannableStringBuilder to reduce the size of h , m and s .
i was expecting it to replace zeros in the text view but it is removing it and writing new number . in short i am messed up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

Try using Strings features (I haven't tested):

```
String formattedSecond = second + Html.fromHtml("<sub><small>" + s + "</small></sub>")

secondTextView.setText(formattedSecond);
```

**Second Method:**

You can add an extra `TextView` aligned in Right (End) Bottom of each `TextView` of smaller size both inside a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aa"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bb"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="S"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/aa"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/aa" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My problem is that the user typed number should replace zeros then move from right to left . It just display 00 initially then disappear

Answer (score 0):

> *'... When a user type input like "123" the textview should change from right to left like "00h 01m 23s" . I cant figure out how to do this. It should take input like google clock app GOOGLE CLOCK APP ...'*

Utilize a *class structure* to parse the value into *hours*, *minutes*, and *seconds*.

```java
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```

```java
class Time {
    String string = "";
    int h, m, s;

    Time() { }
    Time(String s) { append(s); }

    void append(String s) {
        string += s;
        parse();
    }

    private void parse() {
        int n = string.length();
        if (n < 3) s = parseInt(string);
        else {
            if (n <= 4) m = parseInt(string.substring(0, n - 2));
            else {
                h = parseInt(string.substring(0, n - 4));
                m = parseInt(string.substring(n - 4, n - 2));
            }
            s = parseInt(string.substring(n - 2));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%02dh %02dm %02ds".formatted(h, m, s);
    }
}
String s = "12345";
System.out.println(new Time(s));
```

Output

```
01h 23m 45s
```

Here is an example of an appending value.

```java
Time t = new Time();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    t.append(String.valueOf(i));
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Output

```
00h 00m 01s
00h 00m 12s
00h 01m 23s
00h 12m 34s
01h 23m 45s
12h 34m 56s
123h 45m 67s
1234h 56m 78s
12345h 67m 89s
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping a noobie . Gotta try it .